# Why does Spain's PSOE have such a big problem forming a coalition?

Tags: election, parties, spain, coalition

What was the reason PSOE couldn't or didn't want to form a coalition for six months or so, to the extent that it preferred to have second snap election in a year? I understand that it had at least two potential coalition parters: Unidas Podemos to the left, and Ciudadanos to the right. What were the disagreements that made either coalition impossible?

Answer (score 4):

### Lack of tradition

Since the establishment of democracy, the usual situation was a practical bipartidism between PSOE and AP(now PP), where either:

- A political party obtains a majority of the Parliament (*Congreso de Diputados*), which is enough to have its leader elected as PM.
- A political party obtains a plurality great enough to reach a majority if a regionalist/nationalist party (CiU, PNV, CC); the regionalist party supports more or less the government agenda in exchange of some demands for its constituencies but does not form part of the government.

In this context, a policy of demonizing the opposite party and avoiding compromise was rather useful, as support could be bought without risking alienating the supporters of a party by accepting some of the opposing party policies.

Of course, if you have demonized the other party during the electoral campaign, then making pacts after it gets way more complicated, because both of the parties will have more trouble explaining to their electorate why they are making pacts with "the enemy". Until now it was not an issue thanks to bipartidism, but this has been altered by the apparition/greater influence of new political parties (Podemos, Cs, and lately Vox) which eroded the traditional parties pluralities enough to make majorities impossible and "pluralities plus regionalist support" not enough.

### Leadership of the left

The PSOE has always claimed to be "the left wing party", or at least "the left wing party that has actual chances at winning"<sup>1</sup>. OTOH, those parties did usually acknowledge that they would not be able to win the elections but that they would force the PSOE into more leftist policies than it was willing to perform on its own.

Giving government responsabilities to more leftist parties risks erodes the PSOE claims against those parties and gives Unidas Podemos an opportunity to make its point.

### Electoral tactics

It is heavily speculated that Pedro Sánchez did not have much interest in a deal and instead he was very comfortable with the idea of repeating what happened in 2015-2016.

Then the PP got a plurality but not enough support, its leader (Mariano Rajoy) did not even try to form a government while Pedro Sánchez did try to get support but failed. Then elections were repeated in 2016, with increased support (but stil not enough) for the PP, and the PSOE abstained in order to allow Mariano Rajoy to be elected PM by a plurality<sup>2</sup>. The idea was that if elections were repeated yet again the people would support the candidate with more possibilities to form a government.

In this occasion Pedro Sánchez refused a coalition government, he asked for Unidas Podemos support to get elected which would have given him a free hand to pick different allies for each issue<sup>3</sup> (pacting with PP, Cs or Unidas Podemos at his convenience) but the sensation was that there was not much interest in the PSOE making concessions. He even had the wildcard of the regionalist parties being opposed to any right wing coalition which would include Vox, making it easier to get its support or at least no opposition from them.

As a matter of fact, now that it seems that this strategy has failed, the declarations from Sánchez about the possibility of a government pact seem to be quite softer than they were after the previous elections and that negotiations with Unidas Podemos have been resumed after they broke down in June.

UPDATE: Less than 48 hours after the voting stations did close, PSOE and Unidas Podemos [have announced a preliminary government deal](https://www.lavanguardia.com/politica/20191112/471549481488/gobierno-de-coalicion-pedro-sanchez-pablo-iglesias.html)(link in Spanish), including some of the Unidas Podemos requests which were absolutely vetoed in the previous negotiations.

Which proves that to make a deal it is necessary to want to make a deal...

---

<sup>1</sup>At every election the PSOE would claim for himself the "useful vote" from the left, claiming that votes to IU or Unidas Podemos would be wasted and would actually benefit right wing parties.

<sup>2</sup>As a show of how difficult can be to compromise with the other party, Pedro Sánchez was toppled from the PSOE for not voting against Mariano Rajoy's election as PM even when that was the decision taken by the whole of the PSOE's executive.

<sup>3</sup>In Spain motions of no confidence must be *constructive*; they do not only vote against the current PM but they also must propose a new PM. The almost impossibility of getting the opposition parties to agree to an alternative candidate makes a PM position quite safe even without a majority in Parliament; in 40 years of democracy only one motion of no confidance has succeeded and it was after the PM was indicted for the corruption of his party.

Comment: In countries with a tradition of coalition governments there is no less demonizing other parties (See: half the European countries north of the Alps). Rather, it's the public's acceptance of post-election cross-meridian pacts that's not there.

Comment: Does it mean that there were no significant disagreements over policy between PSOE and UP?

Comment: There are disagreements, specially when related to economy and welfare state, with the PSOE being in practice way more liberal (deficit control, less agressive with taxes) despite claiming to be leftist. That is why a PSOE-Cs pact was considered viable by many with the previous Parliament, but they clashed with the issue of independentism (Cs claiming for harsher actions and in line with PP-Vox, with the PSOE not friendly towards independentism but less heavy handed and more in line with UP). In civil rights there are not many differences among the three.

Answer (score 0):

Spanish political parties are effectively controlled by banks. All of them except Unidas Podemos are / have been financed through bank credits. Banks condone / do not execute the credits, but in exchange gain an enormous power: if one day they would decide to execute those credits, the parties would be ruined.

Corporations also indirectly control parties, but through promise of future employment in their ranks to politicians.

UP, in contrast, have since the beginning been financed by private persons. They want to limit power to banks and corporations. Of course, in turn, banks and corporations do not want that and pressure PSOE not to form government with them.

Then there's the Catalan independent parties. They will only agree to give their support to PSOE in exchange for an agreement that they will be able to legally vote regarding Catalan independence. PSOE does not want either, because most Spanish people don't want to "break Spain" and they know it would be political suicide to agree to such conditions.

The only two options that add up for government are PSOE + UP + Catalans or PSOE + PP. PP is the right wing (not as extreme right as VOX, but close) and many PSOE voters (and PP, for that matter) are against that option as well.

No matter how you look at it, it is difficult to get a viable government.

PS: I am aware that I'm over-simplyfing when explaining the power that banks and corporations have over parties such as PSOE. It helps to get the point across, though.

**EDIT**: The matter with Ciudadanos was similar to that of PP, because of their right-wing ideology. However, they have been rendered irrelevant after the second vote, with only 10 seats.

Comment: PP close to VOX, Cs as right-wing, UP financed by exclusively by private individuals... This is as biased as you can get

Comment: I asked what disagreements there were between the parties. Perhaps PSOE is financed by banks and UP is not, but that still is not a disagreement in itself.

Comment: Independent observers list C's as right wing. Even the OP lists C's as right wing. UP is financed by private individuals and by the money they get from the Congress, never by banks. PP is closer to VOX than to PSOE. They vote together in many things such as the recent controversy about exhuming the dictator. Who's biased here?

Comment: @michau it is fundamental to the issue, because it explains the major discrepancies between two supposedly left-wing parties. When Pedro Sánchez suggested that he wanted to reach an agreement with UP, the president of Banco Santander declared that it would be bad. Next day Sánchez changed his mind.

Comment: @legrojan Who are the independent observers? Cs is self defined as center. OP said Cs is to PSOE's right, not that it is a right wing party. _UP is financed by private individuals and by the money they get from the Congress, never by banks_ citation needed. You didn't state that PP is close**r** to VOX than PSOE, you just said that the two parties are close ideologically. Of course they vote together, they are both right wing. that doesn't mean they are both far-right, that is your opinion.

Comment: @LuisReinstateMonica How come that in the repetition ~30 seats went from Cs to Vox? That massive amount of voters went from self-proclaimed centrist to self-proclaimed extreme right wing in six months? Or the self-proclamation of centrist was to wash their public image? (Notice that even PP defines itself as center on occasion...) PS: (I'm aware that the 30 seats movement is a simplification, but there's some clear movement there)

Comment: @Oxy "_self-proclaimed extreme right wing_" is it self-proclaimed? There is a shift to the right, that is undeniable, but the voter goes from center to center-right and those from there go to right/far-right. For Cs's voters it all comes down to the separatist issues,  they are more likely to shift to the center-right (PP) due to the center-left (PSOE) being what they consider soft on that matter. It's also important the polarization of these last elections, Cs is not relevant on the they vs us rhetoric as they try to represent the center

Comment: @LuisReinstateMonica Self proclaimed as in they shout "we are extreme right" at meetings. Literally. I still am not convinced by your impression that C's is a centrist party, not even after they say it. Their base was mostly coming from PP originally, their interventions usually are more radical than those of PP, their founders are friends with fascist flag bearers, their lines are filled with known falangists... the only ones that I know that really think they are centrists are senile old ladies that can't remember their granddaughter's names parroting what they saw a the last TV afternoon

Comment: @Oxy The party has denied being far right on several interviews, they don't define themselves as a far-right party. I could not find any source for those shouts you claim but the Wikipedia has several sources were they deny it. I'm not arguing if they are or are not, but they definitely avoid the term. Cs also had several important members from PSOE and UPyD, I've only seen them sound more "radical" than PP when talking about Catalonia and Spain. They are on PP's left on almost every other issue. They have also reach coalitions with both sides, which is unthinkable for every other party.

Comment: @LuisReinstateMonica The shouts were referring to vox, sorry if I was not clear enough. While you are right about other issues referring to C's, on any other issue that's not catalan and vasque related, they swap stance on every province, so I'd argue they are not definable by them. And let's not forget any official reproval of franquist or fascist sentences, laws or anything related to the dictatorship. They always voted with the right on those, and those are pretty much the "true" tell of right and left in Spain (I'd come to think that even more than lowering or increasing business taxes).

Comment: @Oxy I know it was about Vox, that's why I found it weird, they are constantly denying being **far** right. I'm not arguing if they are or not, but they are very explicit when they define their ideology as not far-right. They claim that the term is part of a campaign by the media against them that does not represent their ideology. I think swapping position so much is what hurt Cs in these last elections, but on the dictatorship issues they have not always voted with the right wing parties, they voted in favor of moving Franco's tomb 2 years ago and they abstained on the last voting.

Comment: @LuisReinstateMonica They can label themselves whatever they fancy. It walks like a duck and quacks like a duck... The parties that congratuled vox the loudest along the whole europe are also considered extreme right by international press. Considering arguments of media campaign against them on international level as honest reaches the point of ridiculous. You can't argue with people that labels the whole world's media as liars, the only truth being what they say. That argument lends itself as a further clue towards their extremist views.

Comment: @LuisReinstateMonica And on fascist laws, I'm talking about historical memory laws, which they define as biased. Biased to the left, to be exactly, because they do not criminalize communist parties enough. They all quack. But hey! They say they are not ducks!

Comment: @Oxy again, I'm not arguing whether they are or not, but it is not self proclaimed as you said.

Comment: @LuisReinstateMonica The first link (minute 4:00) should be to an interview where Vox president refers to adjectives as fascist, falangist, extreme right, etc are medals for them. If the insults that you choose as medals do not define you as self-proclaimed "adjective", what does? Homosexuals used the same strategy with "gay", because they are proud, and to remove stigma. Like he is doing now with those adjectives. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rOACgrfSx9E The second link are "duck walks" https://www.elplural.com/politica/dos-nuevos-candidatos-de-vox-con-pasado-fascista-y-nazi_216298102

Comment: @Oxy **you seem to be focused in proving how they are extremists, I don't care about that.** Those links are not evidence about **them claiming to be far right**, the first is an attack on the mainstream media and he uses it to point out how much the "fake news" establishment hates them. The second link is irrelevant, it's the ideas they defend, not who defends them what defines their ideology. And again, what I'm arguing is that they don't define themselves as far right, not that they are/aren't.